# Allow insecure protocols, android gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I recently updated my android studio to Arctic Fox and got an error in my project

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'so10'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is     unsupported. Switch Maven repository 
'maven3(http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols.
 See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.
```

This is my gradle where the problem occurs

```
repositories {
    // maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://raw.github.com/Raizlabs/maven-releases/master/releases' }
    maven { url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'}
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'  }
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Add allowInsecureProtocol = true for all unsecure http in repositories

Comment: What does "This is my gradle" mean? build.gradle?

Comment: @TheincredibleJan `build.gradle`

Comment: @AshrafAmin Yeah, the Gradle documentation says that too. But the page this message directs you to doesn't give the slightest indication **where** you need to do that.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

For insecure HTTP connections in Gradle 7+ versions, we need to specify a boolean [allowInsecureProtocol](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol) as true to `MavenArtifactRepository` closure.
Since you have received this error for `sonatype` repository, you need to set the repositories as below:

1. Groovy DSL

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
    // other repositories ...
}
```

2. Kotlin DSL

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots")
        isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
    // other repositories ...
}
```

Comment: What is the syntax for configuring both `url` and `allowInsecureProtocol` on the same line?

Comment: Well, that's Groovy, so you could separate the statements using `;` if you want them to be on the same line.

Comment: Add allowInsecureProtocol = true for all unsecure http in repositories

Comment: My problem got solved by adding `allowInsecureProtocol = true` in my (Windows) C:\Users\<userid>\.gradle\init.gradle file

Comment: You now need to use it as `allowInsecureProtocol(true)`

Comment: @TheDeepThinker I only find "init.gradle" in samples directories of old Gradle (5.4.1). Why do you have it in your user\.gradle path and how is it used bei your project? Looks like voodoo...

Comment: I just upgraded Gradle from 4.2.2 to 7.3.1 in an old project and allowInsecureProtocol = true is simply ignored. :( setAllowInsecureProtocol(true) doesn't do anything, too...

Comment: Ok. I didn't remember and realized a little bit slowly that there are 2 build.gradle: 1st in  the main directory of the project. 2nd in the app folder of the project...

Answer (score 45):

or you can just replace `HTTP` with `HTTPS`.

Comment: Maybe you can't if you use your own mirror that doesn't support SSL.

Comment: Not just like that, you'll need a trusted certificate.

Comment: It worked trying this and with a single letter "S" :)

Comment: It's not always the best solution, as if you have vpn for example it will slow down the build significantly

Answer (score 27):

For those using the Kotlin DSL, the property name is different `isAllowInsecureProtocol`

```
maven {
    url = uri("http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots")
    isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Note that Gradle 7 onwards, **any** insecure URL is blocked, not only for repositories, so applying scripts would also fail.

```
apply from: "http://mycompany.com/buildscript.gradle"
```

> Applying script plugins from insecure URIs, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported.

If you can't use HTTPS for whatever reasons, then do the following:

```
apply from: resources.text.fromInsecureUri("http://mycompany.com/buildscript.gradle")
```

However, if I were a Gradle dev, I'd provide a `org.gradle.allow-insecure-protocol=true` to be set in the `gradle.properties` and be done. I've opened https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18006 for that.

Answer (score 12):

Add allowInsecureProtocol = true for all unsecure http in repositories e.g.

```
maven {
        url "http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }

maven {
        url "http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven/"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

For me, coding the assignment statement "allowInsecureProtocol = true" stopped working** in a recent workspace using Gradle 7.x (the reason as yet, is unknown.)
I found that when I instead coded **setAllowInsecureProtocol(true)** and it was OK again.

```
 maven {    url "http://myinsecure/repository..."; 
            setAllowInsecureProtocol(true);
            // allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
```

I have no info about exactly when the assignment statement stopped working.

*Also, regarding comments about using **https** instead - I get it - it's good advice, but in this instance that is out of my control.*

** referring to the build.gradle ...maven clauses

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but in my case setAllowInsecureProtocol(true); this is also not working

Comment: Greetings! @Shubham - would you please clarify for me : Have you also tried using the assignment form "    allowInsecureProtool = true  " and that was also failing? also which Gradle version number are you on?

Comment: Thanks @pete for reply. The issue is now fixed. Need to use allowInsecureProtocol = true in Publishing as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem,by change my gradle version.Because my project need gradle version is lower than the Android Studio given.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I tried to switch to maven2 solved my problem

```
 maven2 {
            url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
```

Comment: No candidates found for method call maven2.