# Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gradle, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using gradle 4.8. I want to create an elasticsearch plugin. I am using jdk9. The elasticsearch version, I am using is 5.6.16. When I clicked on the build button inside intellij idea, It is giving me the below error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
```

> Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven4(http://35.164.44.153/artifactory/jcenter)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow insecure protocols, android gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68585885/allow-insecure-protocols-android-gradle)

Comment: No, it works for elastic search version > 7. I am using 5.6.16 and gradle v4.8

Comment: The output from the build script contains a link to the Gradle 7.3.1 documentation. That means that (no matter what you think your gradle version is) you build script is being built using Gradle 7.3.1 - Gradle helpfully inserts its running version into the generated link. And: you must be running at least on Gradle 6.0 to get that message as a warning: it was introduced with Gradle 6.0 - Gradle 4.8 can never generate a message like that.

Comment: Yeah, you were absolutely right! I checked my gradle version in the terminal and observed that I was using gradle 7.3.1 globally. Although, I had selected gradle 4.8 inside my project in intellij idea but still, at the time of creating the build, it was using the global gradle version 7.3.1 in my system. Then, I tried building my project using the ./gradlew build and it solved my issue. Thank you so much Thomas! Have a good day!

Comment: Great! thanks Thomas. It's also working well for me. Good job! try to answer it.