# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:endpointsServer'. why?

Tags: java, cloud

After updating to Gradle 7.3.0 I having this message error :

> Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven4(http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0-milestone-1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactReposit... for more details

any suggestions?

Comment: Well, the system seems to want to you either use `https://...` urls or explicitly allow the use of `http` which is unsecure due to the lack of encryption. For the latter have a look here which might help you (I'm no expert on Gradle though): https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol

Comment: You might have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68585885/allow-insecure-protocols-android-gradle

Comment: thanks , but I can't understand what the https:// that needed for the app:endpointsServer'?

Answer (score 0):

so what solve it ,it's just adding -4- to Maven , something like Maven4 instead of just Maven in the app build Gradle Mavens declarations.