# Allow insecure protocols, android gradle, aliyun maven

Tags: android, maven, gradle

When I download a new android project from git, I met this problem:

> Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven(http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/repositories/jcenter)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.

In addition, I've viewed this [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68585885/allow-insecure-protocols-android-gradle) without an answer. Because I have found no 'aliyun' maven usage in the project by 'Search Everywhere' and 'Find In Path' .You can see my problem in the follow picture.

[details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ncne.png)
[search res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wPcR.png)

**project root path**
settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "viewer"
include ':app', ':daogenerator'
```

**project root path**
build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**module app**
build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

if (file('google-services.json').exists()) {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    ndkVersion '23.1.7779620'

    flavorDimensions "distribute"
    productFlavors {
        appCenter {
            dimension "distribute"
        }
        googlePlay {
            dimension "distribute"
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xjs.viewer"
        minSdkVersion 23
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 111
        versionName "1.9.4.2"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resConfigs "zh", "zh-rCN", "zh-rHK", "zh-rTW",
                "es", "ja", "ko", "fr", "de", "th"
        testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
        ndk {
            moduleName "native-lib"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a" , "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ''
            }
        }
    }

    lint {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        abortOnError true
        checkReleaseBuilds true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY', '"com.hippo.viewer.fileprovider"'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY', '"com.hippo.viewer.debug.fileprovider"'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java-gen'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }


}

task copyNotice(type: Copy) {
    from '../NOTICE.html'
    into './src/main/assets'
    finalizedBy ":daogenerator:executeDaoGenerator"
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    task -> task.dependsOn copyNotice
}

clean {
    delete file('src/main/assets/NOTICE.html').absolutePath
}

dependencies {
......
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        .......
    }
}
```

***Please help me./(ㄒoㄒ)/~~***

updated my gradle version to 7.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by updata Android  Studio to newest version....
I don't know what happend definitely.