# Gradle allow insecure protocol in initialization script configured repository

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to write an initialization script as explained [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:init_script_plugins). So I wrote an `init.gradle.kts` file and put in the following code

```
import java.net.URI

apply<EnterpriseRepositoryPlugin>()

class EnterpriseRepositoryPlugin : Plugin<Gradle> {
    companion object {
        const val ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL = "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }

    override fun apply(gradle: Gradle) {
        // ONLY USE ENTERPRISE REPO FOR DEPENDENCIES
        gradle.allprojects {
            repositories {

                // Remove all repositories not pointing to the enterprise repository url
                all {
                    if (this !is MavenArtifactRepository || url.toString() != ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL) {
                        project.logger.lifecycle("Repository ${(this as? MavenArtifactRepository)?.url ?: name} removed. Only $ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL is allowed")
                        remove(this)
                    }
                }

                // add the enterprise repository
                add(maven {
                    name = "STANDARD_ENTERPRISE_REPO"
                    url = uri(ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

data class RepositoryData(val name: String, val url: URI)

allprojects {
    tasks.register("repos") {
        val repositoryData = repositories.withType<MavenArtifactRepository>().map { RepositoryData(it.name, it.url) }
        doLast {
            repositoryData.forEach {
                println("repository: ${it.name} ('${it.url}')")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the added task that list the repos

```
 ./gradlew --init-script init.gradle.kts repos
```

it outputs

```
repository: STANDARD_ENTERPRISE_REPO ('http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/')
```

as expected.

But when I use that initialization script with another project that needs to download artifacts, gradle says

```
> Switch Maven repository 'STANDARD_ENTERPRISE_REPO(http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols.
> For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol in the Gradle documentation.
```

The documentation that the error message points to says that I should set `allowInsecureProtocol  = true`, but where should I do that?

If I add it to my init script it doesn't work. I did the following edit to the `init.gradle.kts` I showed you above:

```
add(maven {
      name = "STANDARD_ENTERPRISE_REPO"
      url = uri(ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL)
      allowInsecureProtocol  = true
})
```

But then gradle says:

```
Script compilation error:

Line 27:                         allowInsecureProtocol  = true
^ Unresolved reference: allowInsecureProtocol
```

So how should I set that property to a repository added via an initialization script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax in Kotlin DSL to allow repository access over standard HTTP is to write:

```
maven {
    isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
}
```

Comment: Oops, I was confused by the groovy vs. kotlin dsl. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68586017/974186